# Permalinks only work from home page

Tags: seo, wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to get pretty permalinks working on my wordpress site.

From the home page, every product is redirected to the pretty permalink just fine. However:

1. If I try to directly go to a permalink (say www.mysite.com/product/pretty-link-1, i.e. not via the home page), I am redirected back to the home page. Is this going to be an issue for SEO indexing purposes?
2. None of the permalinks show up in a sitemap (since I cannot directly go to those URLs). Is this an SEO issue?

Thanks a lot, I am trying to get this site functional today.
AV

Comment: Are you using woocommerce? Have set up the pages ie shop etc. In the general settings page is your site url and home url correct.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. It will be an issue but up to certain extent. Pretty URL are often associated with high quality websites and better for usability and UX. As long as you can reach the product pages from the homepage you won’t be having any issues in terms of indexation. If the pages are accessible they will always be indexed.
2. This is no an issue, search engines do not rely on the information provided in the sitemap. But here, I can see that there is definitely a problem in the way WordPress is handling the URLs.

You need to check if you are selecting the right permalink option in Settings->Permalinks and make sure you save it before leaving this section.

Then, If you Wordpress is running on an Apache server and is in the root, you need to check if the permalink rules has been written to the .htaccess file.

Here is how the Wordpress rules in the .htaccess file should look like after you saved the settings:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I believe this is the answer for your question in this forum related to SEO.

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400749/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-htaccess-seems-ok-but-getting-404-error-on-pa), however, might help you with your Wordpress permalink related issue. If not consider posting a more specific question in another forum:

When you go from your homepage do you see permalinks? Or ugly URL?

From the products pages and using the main navigation menu, can you go to other products pages?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Here, you can see for yourself. From the home page, I see pretty permalinks. From the product pages, no - I cannot go to other product pages. That is part of the problem. http://coinandcryptodomains.com/

Comment: @user2736158 Oh I see, you are using an NGINX web server. I said that the problem is coming from the way the web server is configured. Did you managed to solved? how? my answer here is about how to resolve the issue via htaccess in nginx the equivalent is nginx.conf. Any way, did my answer helped?